# paypal IPN not working when using email function

Tags: php, email, paypal, paypal-ipn

I'm implementing payments through paypal on my website and I'm having trouble with the Instant Payment Notification's,

I've got the following base code copied from the paypal's example:

```
<?php
// CONFIG: Enable debug mode. This means we'll log requests into 'ipn.log' in the same directory.
// Especially useful if you encounter network errors or other intermittent problems with IPN (validation).
// Set this to 0 once you go live or don't require logging.
define("DEBUG", 1);
// Set to 0 once you're ready to go live
define("USE_SANDBOX", 1);
define("LOG_FILE", "./ipn.log");

$raw_post_data = file_get_contents('php://input');
$raw_post_array = explode('&', $raw_post_data);
$myPost = array();
foreach ($raw_post_array as $keyval) {
    $keyval = explode ('=', $keyval);
    if (count($keyval) == 2)
        $myPost[$keyval[0]] = urldecode($keyval[1]);
}
// read the post from PayPal system and add 'cmd'
$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
if(function_exists('get_magic_quotes_gpc')) {
    $get_magic_quotes_exists = true;
}
foreach ($myPost as $key => $value) {
    if($get_magic_quotes_exists == true && get_magic_quotes_gpc() == 1) {
        $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
    } else {
        $value = urlencode($value);
    }
    $req .= "&$key=$value";
}
// Post IPN data back to PayPal to validate the IPN data is genuine
// Without this step anyone can fake IPN data
if(USE_SANDBOX == true) {
    $paypal_url = "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
} else {
    $paypal_url = "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
}
$ch = curl_init($paypal_url);
if ($ch == FALSE) {
    return FALSE;
}
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $req);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, 1);
if(DEBUG == true) {
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, 1);
}

// Set TCP timeout to 30 seconds
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Connection: Close'));

$res = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch) != 0) // cURL error
    {
    if(DEBUG == true) { 
        error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "Can't connect to PayPal to validate IPN message: " . curl_error($ch) . PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
    }
    curl_close($ch);
    exit;
} else {
        // Log the entire HTTP response if debug is switched on.
        if(DEBUG == true) {
            error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "HTTP request of validation request:". curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT) ." for IPN payload: $req" . PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
            error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "HTTP response of validation request: $res" . PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
        }
        curl_close($ch);
}
// Inspect IPN validation result and act accordingly
// Split response headers and payload, a better way for strcmp
$tokens = explode("\r\n\r\n", trim($res));
$res = trim(end($tokens));
if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {


    mail('try@website.com', 'New Order', 'New Order', 'From: support@website.com');



    if(DEBUG == true) {
        error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "Verified IPN: $req ". PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
    }
} else if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0) {
    // log for manual investigation
    // Add business logic here which deals with invalid IPN messages
    if(DEBUG == true) {
        error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "Invalid IPN: $req" . PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
    }
}
?>
```

If I remove the mail function everything works as intended, the log is written once and a "sent" state appears at the IPN history.

Now, when the mail function is used, everything is executed for like 8 times, this means 8 log writings and 8 emails sent.
Meanwhile The IPN History keeps in "retrying" state turning into "error" state after some time, mention that the http response field is empty in both cases.

Thanks for your time mates.

**Edit 1:**

this is the content in the log file:

```
[2016-04-27 12:19 America/New_York] HTTP request of validation request:POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.1
Host: www.sandbox.paypal.com
Accept: */*
Connection: Close
Content-Length: 1052
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Expect: 100-continue



for IPN payload: bla bla bla
[2016-04-27 12:19 America/New_York] HTTP response of validation request: HTTP/1.1 100 Continue

HTTP/1.1 200 OK

bla bla bla

VERIFIED
```

i think everything is OK, also the apache log doesen't display any error...
**Edit 2:**

Solved, See the solution below.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your mail function is failing and giving a header other than 200 which paypal expects that is why the 8 more retries.
Anyway I edited the code and placed the mail() function within a try catch block and logged the error.

```
    <?php
        // CONFIG: Enable debug mode. This means we'll log requests into 'ipn.log' in the same directory.
        // Especially useful if you encounter network errors or other intermittent problems with IPN (validation).
        // Set this to 0 once you go live or don't require logging.
        define("DEBUG", 1);
        // Set to 0 once you're ready to go live
        define("USE_SANDBOX", 1);
        define("LOG_FILE", "./ipn.log");

        $raw_post_data = file_get_contents('php://input');
        $raw_post_array = explode('&', $raw_post_data);
        $myPost = array();
        foreach ($raw_post_array as $keyval) {
            $keyval = explode ('=', $keyval);
            if (count($keyval) == 2)
                $myPost[$keyval[0]] = urldecode($keyval[1]);
        }
        // read the post from PayPal system and add 'cmd'
        $req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
        if(function_exists('get_magic_quotes_gpc')) {
            $get_magic_quotes_exists = true;
        }
        foreach ($myPost as $key => $value) {
            if($get_magic_quotes_exists == true && get_magic_quotes_gpc() == 1) {
                $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
            } else {
                $value = urlencode($value);
            }
            $req .= "&$key=$value";
        }
        // Post IPN data back to PayPal to validate the IPN data is genuine
        // Without this step anyone can fake IPN data
        if(USE_SANDBOX == true) {
            $paypal_url = "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
        } else {
            $paypal_url = "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
        }
        $ch = curl_init($paypal_url);
        if ($ch == FALSE) {
            return FALSE;
        }
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $req);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, 1);
        if(DEBUG == true) {
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, 1);
        }

        // Set TCP timeout to 30 seconds
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Connection: Close'));

        $res = curl_exec($ch);
        if (curl_errno($ch) != 0) // cURL error
            {
            if(DEBUG == true) { 
                error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "Can't connect to PayPal to validate IPN message: " . curl_error($ch) . PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
            }
            curl_close($ch);
            exit;
        } else {
                // Log the entire HTTP response if debug is switched on.
                if(DEBUG == true) {
                    error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "HTTP request of validation request:". curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT) ." for IPN payload: $req" . PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
                    error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "HTTP response of validation request: $res" . PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
                }
                curl_close($ch);
        }
        // Inspect IPN validation result and act accordingly
        // Split response headers and payload, a better way for strcmp
        $tokens = explode("\r\n\r\n", trim($res));
        $res = trim(end($tokens));
        if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {


            try{
mail('try@website.com', 'New Order', 'New Order', 'From: support@website.com');

}
catch(Exception $e){
error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "Email could not be sent. Error" . $e->getMessage(). PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
}


            if(DEBUG == true) {
                error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "Verified IPN: $req ". PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
            }
        } else if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0) {
            // log for manual investigation
            // Add business logic here which deals with invalid IPN messages
            if(DEBUG == true) {
                error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "Invalid IPN: $req" . PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
            }
        }
        ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i tried the try-catch but no error appears in the log see the post edit please

Answer (score 0):

Okey I finally found the solution, this is only for people working with a virtual private server. The problem for me was the mail function that was taking too long and maybe generating a timeout in the IPN listener,

**To solve this:**
- First you get the hostname tiping `hostname` in the command prompt

- Then I edit the hosts file : `sudo nano /etc/hosts`
  -----------and change this line -> `127.0.0.1 localhost myhostname`
  -----------to this line         -> `127.0.0.1 localhost localhost.localdomain myhostname`

**Source:**
http://deeemm.com/entry/general/fix-your-painfully-slow-php-mail-function